# ¿Cómo funcionan los Servicios de Android en Xamarin?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin

Estoy programando una App en Xamarin que tiene que geoposicionar cada 5 minutos.

Ayer estaba teniendo un problema para ejecutar esta App en segundo plano y por lo que me dijeron tengo que usar servicios para que esto funcione (quiero que al apretar un botón se cierre la ventana y siga trabajando, al igual que lo hace WhatsApp por ejemplo). Ahora el problema que tengo es que no se como ejecutar el servicio...

Alguien podría decirme que estoy haciendo mal? Se que tengo que poner algo en el `OnStartCommand` del Service, pero no sé bien como funcionan los servicios ya que es la primera vez que los uso y no encontré ejemplos muy claros hasta ahora

Acá les dejo los códigos de ejemplo:

Activity:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using System;
using System.IO;
using Android.Util;
using Android.Locations;
using GeoPosicion.Services;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using SQLite;
using GeoPosicion.Modelos;
using System.Collections;
using Android.Telephony;
using System.ComponentModel;


namespace GeoPosicion
{
    [Activity(Label = "GeoPosicion", MainLauncher = true,  Icon = "@drawable/and_geoico", ScreenOrientation = Android.Content.PM.ScreenOrientation.Portrait)]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        Button btnMinimizar;
        Button btnCancelar;
        SQLiteConnection db;


        #region CicloDeVida

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

            btnMinimizar = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnMinimizar);
            btnCancelar = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnCancelar);
            btnMinimizar.Click += btnMinimizar_Click;
            btnCancelar.Click += btnCancelar_Click;
        }

        protected override void OnPause()
        {
            base.OnPause();
        }

        protected override void OnResume()
        {
            base.OnResume();
        }

        protected override void OnDestroy()
        {
            base.OnDestroy();
        }

        #endregion

        #region Eventos

        private void btnMinimizar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RunOnUiThread(() =>{
                StartService(new Intent(this, typeof(ServicioPosicion)));
            });
        }

        private void btnCancelar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        #endregion
    }

}
```

Service:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Util;
using GeoPosicion.Services;
using Android.Locations;
using GeoPosicion.Modelos;
using Android.Telephony;

namespace GeoPosicion
{
    [Service]
    public class ServicioPosicion : Service
    {
        private double latitudA;
        private double longitudA;
        private DateTime horaA;

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();

            App.Current.LocationServiceConnected += (object sender, ServiceConnectedEventArgs e) => {
                // notifica cambio de ubicacion
                App.Current.LocationService.LocationChanged += HandleLocationChanged;
                //notifica cambios de proveedor de ubicacion (el usuario habilita o deshabilita GPS)
                App.Current.LocationService.ProviderDisabled += HandleProviderDisabled;
                App.Current.LocationService.ProviderEnabled += HandleProviderEnabled;
                // notifica cambio del estado del proveedor (GPS no esta disponible)
                App.Current.LocationService.StatusChanged += HandleStatusChanged;
            };
        }

        public static void OnStartCommand()
        {

        }

        public override IBinder OnBind(Intent intent)
        {
            // This is a started service, not a bound service, so we just return null.
            return null;
        }

        public override void OnDestroy()
        {
            base.OnDestroy();

            App.StopLocationService();
        }

        void HandleTimerCallback(object state)
        {

        }

        public void HandleLocationChanged(object sender, LocationChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Android.Locations.Location location = e.Location;

            DateTime HoraActual = DateTime.Now;
            TimeSpan diferencia;
            diferencia = HoraActual - horaA;

            if (diferencia.Minutes >= 5)
            {
                Location locationA = new Location("Punto A");
                locationA.Latitude = latitudA;
                locationA.Longitude = longitudA;

                Location locationB = new Location("Punto B");
                locationB.Latitude = location.Latitude;
                locationB.Longitude = location.Longitude;

                float distancia = locationA.DistanceTo(locationB);
                if (latitudA == 0 || distancia >= 100)
                {
                    Posiciones posiciones = new Posiciones { Fecha = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), hora = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString(), Latitud = location.Latitude.ToString(), Longitud = location.Longitude.ToString() };

                    PosicionTracker pg = new PosicionTracker();
                    pg.Fecha = DateTime.Now;
                    pg.Longitud = Convert.ToDecimal(location.Longitude);
                    pg.Latitud = Convert.ToDecimal(location.Latitude);

                    latitudA = location.Latitude;
                    longitudA = location.Longitude;
                }

                horaA = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }

        public void HandleProviderDisabled(object sender, ProviderDisabledEventArgs e)
        {
            //  Log.Debug(logTag, "Evento Deshabilitado para proveedor de ubicaciones generado");
        }

        public void HandleProviderEnabled(object sender, ProviderEnabledEventArgs e)
        {
            //  Log.Debug(logTag, "Evento habilitado para proveedor de ubicaciones generado");
        }

        public void HandleStatusChanged(object sender, StatusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //   Log.Debug(logTag, "Evento Cambiado para proveedor de ubicaciones generado");
        }
    }
}
```

Gracias de antemano!

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya encontré la respuesta a este problema.

Lo hice con Bound Services y aca dejo 2 videos que explican como funcionan.

Parte 1: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W1BxxOCsB5k

Parte 2: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q7ddaqW1QaY